# Session closed for user root

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I'm trying to use an old pc as server (ubuntu desktop LTS 22.04.02) and to connect from my new personal computer (ubuntu desktop LTS 22.04.02).

The command `ssh -Y me@the other ip address` worked **once and never again**.

Since then I get, from my new pc,

`ssh: connect to host [ip] port [port]: Connection timed out`

while the output in `/var/log/auth.log` (my old pc) is

```
Aug 1 ...omissis...: pam_unix(cron:session):session opened for user root (uid=0) by (uid=0)
Aug 1 ...omissis...: pam_unix(cron:session):session closed for user root
```

`systemctl status sshd` says it's active and enabled
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is in order, as `PasswordAythentication` is set to `yes`

I don't know what to do

thank you very much in advance

EDIT: the old pc is not pingable from my new pc, while it is by itself. They both can ping themselves but not eachother. They are connected to the same hotspot (my phone)

Comment: The details in your post do not make sense. The error `Connection timed out` means there was no connection to the host. There would not be host log entries for that connection attempt.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, there are indeed connection attempts log. I see your point, but I re-did the ls command to verify that, and the file was changed in the way I described.

Comment: Are you running an OS firewall or usage blocking filter setting like `MaxAuthTries` or a software product that monitors SSH auth attempts? More details on your configuration are required.

Comment: Dear John, thank you for your interest, I'm currently abroad away from my old pc and I won't be able to access it until christmas. I will keep the question open, but I doubt that I will be able to try anything any time soon. Thank you again

Comment: What you post a question, you must be ready to respond to comments and requests for information. Delete your post. Once you are available create a new post.